# how to test vuejs props with Typescript + Jest

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, jestjs, nuxt.js

i have the following prop in a single file component **(Nuxt.js)**

```
export default {
  props: {
    message: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      validator: (value) => {
        return ['a', 'b', 'c'].includes(value)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to test everything regarding this `message` property, so I created a test

`Test.spec.js`

```
it('should be required, a String and validates correctly', () => {
  const wrapper = shallowMount(Test, {
    propsData: {
      message: 'a',
    }
  })
  const messageProp = wrapper.vm.$options.props.message

  expect(messageProp.required).toBeTruthy()
  expect(messageProp.type).toBe(String)
  expect(messageProp.validator('a')).toBeTruthy()
  expect(messageProp.validator('x')).toBeFalsy()
})
```

Everything works perfectly, no errors.

But when I try to do the same with Typescript **(Nuxt.js + Typescript)**

```
<script lang="ts">
import Vue, { PropOptions } from 'vue'

export default Vue.extend({
  props: {
    message: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      validator: (value) => {
        return ['a', 'b', 'c'].includes(value)
      }
    } as PropOptions<string>
  }
})
</script>
```

I get this error
`Test.spec.ts`

[image]

```
console.log(wrapper.vm.$options.props)
```

[image]

can someone help me make this work or a better way that i can test everything regarding the props?

Comment: Why are you using Vue.extend in one and not the other?

Comment: @AluanHaddad one project is typescript the other is not.

Comment: And that should not imply an logical differences. If you are calling a function in TS you would always call it in JS. I think you need to research typescript. TypeScript is JavaScript + optional static type annotations.

Comment: @AluanHaddad the code you see `export default Vue.extend({})` is a scaffolding generated by nuxt, when you choose javacript, it's just `export default {}` when you choose typescript at installation, it is automatically generated `export default Vue.extend({})`

Comment: @AluanHaddad I researched for hours and got nowhere so I decided to ask for help here, I thought the community helped other devs. sorry.